# conformal flat near a point

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, and $x\in M$ be a fixed point.

**Q** Can we find a conformal transformation such that near $x$ we can write  $e^{2u}g$ as $(dx^1)^2+\cdots+(dx^n)^2$?

Since the question is local, we can replace $M$ with $\mathbb R^n$.

(PS: Any reference is welcome.)

Comment: Not every metric on $ \mathbb{R}^n $ is conformal to the standard one.

Comment: You want to compute the Weyl tensor of the conformal structure. This is a nice example where we can apply Cartan's method of equivalence, for example.

Answer (score 5):

To close this question: the problem of finding whether a pseudo-Riemannian metric is conformally flat is, not surprisingly, independent of signature and solved a very long time ago. In dimensions 4 or more, the metric is conformally flat just when the [Weyl tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_tensor) vanishes, as discussed at length in the Wikipedia article on the Weyl tensor. In dimension three, the Weyl tensor vanishes and there is a higher order invariant, called the [Cotton tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotton_tensor) whose vanishing characterizes conformal flatness in dimension three. In dimensions zero, one and two all pseudo-Riemannian metrics are locally conformally flat.